# Set less as pager in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I can't set `less` as pager in psql.

This is my environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PostgreSQL 9.3.5
- psql 9.3.5
- Fish shell 2.1.1

`~/.psqlrc` contents:

```
# \setenv PAGER less
\x auto
\timing
\set VERBOSITY verbose
\pset null 'NULL'
\pset pager on
\set HISTSIZE
\set PROMPT1 '(%n@%M:%>) [%/] > '
\set PROMPT2 '%[%033[8m%](%n@%M:%>) [%/] >[%033[0m%]%'
```

`env | grep PAGER`:

```
PAGER=less
```

Neverthless this, when I digit <kbd>\d</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> I get:

```
table another_table
table another_table
...
--More--
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158269/can-we-use-something-better-than-more-for-tab-completion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The display of this line (`--More--`) and the forward-only scrolling capability in tab-completion come from the internal pager of the `readline` library, as opposed to an external pager. `psql` lets this library handle the UI-side of tab-completion.

This paging may be turned off in `.inputrc` with `set page-completions to off` , but it's not replaceable by an external program, at least not in the current versions of GNU readline.

In the context of displaying query results, the `PAGER` environment variable normally works as documented.

Comment: _In the context of displaying query results, the PAGER environment variable normally works as documented._ So it's separated from the PostgreSQL pager setting, I didn't realize it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another case is when you got error in psql.exe:

'less' is not recognized as an internal or external command

when trying to get some result by SQL:
[image: qwe]

Easy solution is turn off pager:

\pset pager off

[image: qwe2]

DONE!

Answer (score 0):

Using the postgres command line client , psql

```
\o |less -S -X && stty sane
```